# Expo <Camera> component does not work on the Web on mobile

Tags: react-native, web, camera, expo

I am using this basic code to get access to the camera using `Expo` `Camera` component.

It works on a computer, but when I open it on iPhone/iPad it shows me empty space (although it asks for permissions and shows `camera in use` symbol. I tried both Safari and Chrome. I use `https`

```
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';

export default function Add({ navigation }){

  const [cameraPermission, setCameraPermission] = useState(null);
  const [camera, setCamera] = useState(null);


  const permisionFunction = async () => {
    // here is how you can get the camera permission
    const cameraPermission = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();

    setCameraPermission(cameraPermission.status === 'granted');

    
    if (
      cameraPermission.status !== 'granted'
    ) {
      alert('Permission for media access needed.');
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    permisionFunction();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View >
        <Camera
          ref={(ref) => setCamera(ref)}
        />
     </View>);
}
```

Any idea what can cause it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue thread [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/13431).

The issue seems to be with `Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync()` that does not properly close the camera, so subsequent attempts to use the camera are failing. (This is my guess, I have not debugged the code).

Once I disabled `Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync()` call, the code works.